# how to use systemd-boot on a KVM vitual server?

Tags: arch-linux, kvm, uefi, vps, systemd-boot

I'm installing Arch Linux manually (using an ISO image) on a KVM virtual private server.

I'm booted into the ISO image, but it was not booted with EFI.

Is it possible to use `systemd-boot` in this circumstance?

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235198) post doesn't appear to have a good answer for my situation:

The [instructions](https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-arch-linux-on-a-vultr-server) I'm following suggest a bootloader needs to be installed. They actually suggest `grub` should be installed.

```
pacman -S grub
grub-install /dev/vda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

However, I would prefer `systemd-boot` if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a kernel and bootloader to boot a KVM virtual machine.

But you can only use systemd-boot if your KVM virtual machine is configured to boot via UEFI, as it is a UEFI-only bootloader. Most VPS providers, including Vultr and Digital Ocean, only support legacy boot (for now). When these providers expand to support UEFI boot, or when you find another provider which does, then you can use systemd-boot there. For legacy boot, grub is your best bet.